# How to get the boundary points from ConcaveHullMesh in 3D?

Tags: graphics3d, computational-geometry, boundary-conditions

I am trying to visualize the boundary points of a quadratic polynomial that has only real roots where I treat the coefficients as coordinate values. But I am having a problem visualizing them because I don't know how to get the points that are on the boundary of the concave hull.

Here is the code to illustrate the problem and an example of what I tried:

```
n = 5000; (* Number of random sets to generate *)
data = Table[
  {a, b, c} = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 3];
  discriminant = b^2 - 4*a*c;
  If[discriminant  >= 0, {a, b, c}, Nothing],
  {n}
];

ListPointPlot3D[data, AxesLabel -> {"a", "b", "c"}, PlotLabel -> "Coefficients of Quadratics with D >= 0"]

chm = ConcaveHullMesh[data]

boundaryPoints = MeshCoordinates[chm]
```

But

`Length[boundaryPoints]` is the same as `Length[data]`.

How do I get the boundary points of the concave hull in 3D?

Comment: Maybe `bdp =MeshCoordinates[RegionBoundary[chm]]; Length[bdp]`.

Comment: @cvgmt Yep, I didn't know that keyword and when I searched terms, I could not find it. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you want "ConcaveHull" and not "ConvexHull"?

Comment: @DanielHuber Yes, I want ConcaveHull.